# Cannot store a durable job because 'it already exists'

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net, job-scheduling

What I am trying to do is to remove a trigger from my job and assign it a brand new one. I have limited my users to be only able to add one trigger per job. But I would like to give them the option to remove that trigger and add a new trigger to the same job.

In order to not to lose my job information, I add my jobs as `durable`.

Then I find the trigger that is associated with that job and use

```
sched.UnscheduleJob(trigger.Key);
```

to remove the trigger (which should also unschedule the job too unless it is `durable` which is my case).

Now I know that the trigger has been removed but my job is still there.
When I try to add my new trigger to this job using

```
sched.ScheduleJob(job, newTrigger);
```

I get the error:

> Couldn't store job: Unable to store Job: 'MYGROUP.MYJOB', because one
>   already exists with this identification.

And that is what I know, but I still would like to associate the new trigger to this job.

Why does that happen? And how can I add the new trigger to the old job without having to delete the old job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly common error; as you can probably tell, a call to `sched.ScheduleJob(job, newTrigger)` attempts to reinsert the `JobDetail` into the QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS table. This would cause a constraint violation as the primary key to the table is a composite of the scheduler name, the `JobKey` and the `JobGroup`. Quartz neatly handles this internally and gives you a meaningful error instead of just reporting a primary key violation.

The solution is actually as simple as replacing your old trigger with the new one.

```
    ITrigger newTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                         .WithCronSchedule(newExpression)
                         .WithIdentity(newTriggerKey)
                         .StartNow()
                         .Build();

    sched.RescheduleJob(existingTrigger.Key, newTrigger);
```